# ListPicker, как получить текст из выбранного итема?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

На странице есть ListPicker, как получить текст из выбранного итема?

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="EncodingList">
<toolkit:ListPickerItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="UTF-8" />
<toolkit:ListPickerItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Windows-1251" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На "стеке" ответили, может кому пригодится:

```
var x = ((ListPickerItem)EncodingList.SelectedItem).Content;
```

Comment: Лучше всё же определять контент через `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Спасибо Влад, но из-за двух элементов не хотел городить лишний код. Если бы список был больше - можно было бы массивом в ListPicker загнать.

Comment: @z668: Вы правы, для мелких элементов обычно не хочется городить отдельную VM.